# F5 flood cause to high cpu

Tags: centos, firewall, ddos

I have Centos 6 64bit with Directadmin and CSF.
When someone press F5 on keyboard without leave it, the cpu is being too high.
I dont want to block port 80 by PORTFLOOD of CSF.
I just try to understand how Incapsula and Cloudflare and other services make you or themselves save from that flood without any ip block or delay?

Thank you.

Comment: If a single computer can dos your server by simple refresh... do you run a 100Mhz server with 1 MB RAM ? http request limiting is the "magic" called you are looking for. See [for Apache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131681/how-can-i-implement-rate-limiting-with-apache-requests-per-second) or [for NGINX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12298541/config-of-nginx-to-filter-http-flood?rq=1).

Comment: I have four E5 cores and 10GB memory. Cloudflare and Incapsula are not limiting. How they did it?

Comment: I just tried it on my server and 8 cores go to 100% lol :D CloudFlare makes extensive use of reverse proxies. I think they also have dedicated IDS and/or firewall which limit requests per IP/SSL session/request header/... Maybe it's even better to implement it using iptables than in the webserver.

Comment: No body know how much F5 is dangerous lol :D. But anyway I want know how to do it without any limit, delay or blocking. Do you have any idea for doing that?